# Android App purchase clarification

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am developing a application in android.i want to give some features as free for my users. also they need to purchase to get additional features of the app. How can i achieve this? can any one help me on this regarding to purchase some features only. thanks in advance.

Comment: take a Look at the [Android IAB v3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) and [Android IAB](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Comment: hi @UsmanKurd does the above like have options for enabling some fratures only for paid?

Answer (score 1):

There are total 3 type of in-App purchase items available

1. Managed(consumable and non consumable)
2. Unmanaged(removed from in-app
   version-3)
3. Subscription(Monthly and yearly)

for details check links given by @usman above in comments.